# How to format a DataSet to contain multiple data in a single column?

Tags: c#

I have a situation like: From DB I am getting data like

```
-------------------------------------------------
ID  BOOK_NAME AUTHOR REMARKS
1   ASP.Net   xyz    It is a good book.
1   ASP.Net   xyz    I like this book.
1   ASP.Net   xyz    It worth buying.
2   C#.net    abc    It is a average book.
2   C#.net    abc    It is good for beginner.
--------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, i have multiple remarks for a specific book detail. I am getting it as a DataSet. My problem is to remove the duplicate rows and set it something like in a DataSet.

```
-------------------------------------------------
ID  BOOK_NAME AUTHOR REMARKS
1   ASP.Net   xyz    It is a good book.
                     I like this book.
                     It worth buying.
2   C#.net    abc    It is a average book.
                     It is good for beginner.
--------------------------------------------------
```

After creating the DataSet i have to convert to XML by using the dataSetObj.GetXml();

Any idea how to do this in C#?

Comment: How does your select looks like ? Do you use Join ?

Comment: What is your DB schema? You need to split your data into two tables but to write a query for them I need your DB schema.

Comment: You do understand that having multiple rows with the same row id is a mistake right?  Each row should have a unique id.  The name of the book and the author of the book would allow you to have multiple "reviews" and break a basic rule about database schemas.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep remaining rows blank. You cannot create customized dataset on your own as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

Put your data in to a DataTable

Store the first row's, first cells content

Loop through the entire grid from the 2nd row till the end 
and check if the Name column's value is same or not.
If it is same, then replace the value with empty string 
else continue with the new value. The above process will repeat itself

```
private void GenerateUniqueData(int cellno)
{
    //Logic for unique names

    //Step 1:

    string initialnamevalue = grdUniqueNames.Rows[0].Cells[cellno].Text;

    //Step 2:        

    for (int i = 1; i < grdUniqueNames.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        if (grdUniqueNames.Rows[i].Cells[cellno].Text == initialnamevalue)
            grdUniqueNames.Rows[i].Cells[cellno].Text = string.Empty;
        else
            initialnamevalue = grdUniqueNames.Rows[i].Cells[cellno].Text;
    }
}
```